# How should I phrase question sentences?

Tags: questions, word-order, subject-auxiliary-inversion

1. What are you doing?
2. What you are doing?

Are both sentences correct? If so, then what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

Your first is correct, asking what a person is doing.

But your second sentence is incorrect as it cannot stand alone like that. By phrasing like so in your second sentence, it becomes part of a statement rather than a question. So an example would be:

> **What you are doing** is incorrect as there isn't an extra wire in that diagram.

Answer (score 0):

**What are you doing?** This works as a stand alone question.

*What you are doing* is a sentence fragment. It has the subject of a *statement* but is missing its predicate.

```
"What are you doing," she asked? "'What you are doing' is a sentence fragment."
```